# Comparing Object Files with ObjDump

Tags: elf, debug-symbols, objdump, texas-instruments

So I am trying to compare two ELF files original/gen_twiddle_fft16x16_imre.oe674 and new/gen_twiddle_fft16x16_imre.oe674 to see if they are the same thing. I have a hunch that they are, but, I can't tell exactly.

I can't just compare the code size and hope for the best, because their sizes are a few hundred bytes.

I run the dissassembler:

```
/ti_packages/all_packages/ccs1200/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-armllvm_2.1.0.LTS/bin/tiarmobjdump -D directory/gen_twiddle_fft16x16_imre.oe674
```

and I get:

```
gen_twiddle_fft16x16_imre.oe674:    file format elf32-unknown
/ti_packages/all_packages/ccs1200/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-armllvm_2.1.0.LTS/bin/tiarmobjdump: error: 'gen_twiddle_fft16x16_imre.oe674': can't find target: : error: unable to get target for 'unknown--', see --version and --triple
```

for both files. I look at the symbol table, and they are exactly the same, except for this part at the top:

original/:

```
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 .hidden **TIsUkimy7q4**
```

new/:

```
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 .hidden **TIgFVpK1DaG**
```

---

**Questions:**

1. What could be the reason for this difference / what does this difference mean?
2. Is there anything else I should try?

---

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the reason for this difference / what does this difference mean?

Looks like two randomly-generated symbol names. The difference *likely* doesn't mean *anything*.

> Is there anything else I should try?

Comparing symbol tables isn't going to tell you *anything* useful.

You should compare *disassembly* of the two objects (`objdump -dr` output), and also compare `.data` and `.rodata` in them (which you can dump with `objdump -sj.data ...`, etc.).

If they have identical `.text`, `.data` and `.rodata`, it's *likely* that the two objects are effectively the same.

Comment: I try running the dissassembler (via the -D option which means dissassemble-all) and I get:

/ti_packages/all_packages/ccs1200/ccs/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-armllvm_2.1.0.LTS/bin/tiarmobjdump: error: 'gen_twiddle_fft16x16_imre.oe674': can't find target: : error: unable to get target for 'unknown--', see --version and --triple

So it doesn't help...

Comment: @TheDude Sorry I missed the error. You need to tell `objdump` what's inside of this `elf32` file -- use the appropriate `--triple=...` argument to do that.

Comment: Okay -- I don't know much about the triple argument. Do you have good examples / docs you can link me to?